# Outdoor Wi-Fi implementation (Bandwidth Distribution)

Tags: wireless

Upon applying for a leased line from ISP, and subcription to monthly Bandwidth, how would the bandwidth be distributed per Access Point? Say you have a 40mbps bandwidth from the ISP, how would that be distributed for each user?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi uses [CSMA/CA](http://ilovewifi.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-80211-csmaca-works.html), so all users share the bandwidth.  If there is only one user, she gets all of it.  If there are many, they share it.  Everyone gets (statistically) a time slot in which they can send data.

Comment: What about for multiple access points, how would they share the bandwidth? I understand you can configure a cap per user.

Comment: Assuming all the APs are connected together via Ethernet, they also share the bandwidth.   High end (commercial) APs may have some traffic shaping/policing, but you can't control the client (user) transmissions.  The "cap" only applies when there's contention.  I've never seen it deployed to limit bandwidth per user.  What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: How about for a mesh wireless AP deployment, it's possible to share bandwidth?

Comment: Mesh also uses CSMA/CA, so there's no difference there.  Is there  a specific problem you're trying to solve?